# Showing that a functional sequence is uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be uniformly continuous and define $f_n(x) = f(x+e^{-n})(x \in \mathbb{R}; n \in \mathbb{N})$
Show that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly convergent to $f$.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x,y (= x+ e^{-n}) \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$|e^{-n}|< \delta \implies |f(x+e^{-n})-f(x)|< \epsilon$$

since $$e^{-n}< \delta \implies -n < \ln \delta \implies n > \ln \frac{1}{\delta}$$

so by taking $N > \ln \frac{1}{\delta}$ we have $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
$$n > N \implies|f(x+e^{-n})-f(x)|< \epsilon $$

hence $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent to $f$.

Comment: You proof is valid.

Comment: Yes, this proof is ok :)

Comment: Your proof is correct, but you are doing too much in that first sentence. Don't mention anything about $e^{-n}$ yet, just state the definition of uniformly continuous.

The say "If $N>\ln\frac{1}{\delta}$ then...."

Comment: Oh, and you wrote $y=x+e^{-n}$, but then used $f(x-e^{-n})-f(x)$. See the error there?

Comment: Oh yea that's a typo! I shall fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete version of my suggested edit of your proof (which was not wrong, except for the typo):

> Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, for all $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$:
>   $$|y-x|< \delta \implies |f(y)-f(x)|< \epsilon$$
>
> Take $N > \ln \frac{1}{\delta}$. Then if $n>N$, $|e^{-n}|<\delta$. So for all $x$:  $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|f(x+e^{-n})-f(x)|<\epsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you :). The parts which have been discarded probably belong on scratch paper anyway.

Comment: Yes, you are mixing up the way you figure out the result with the proof of the result.